# Specify date format while parsing date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to parse `7Apr2014`.

Most of the custom parsing solutions suggest string manipulation using regex or some other hack.

In Java I could simply do this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy").parse("07Apr2014")
```

Is there no way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: To directly answer your question, nope. Have a look at http://www.datejs.com/. Also, how do you suppose those Java libs parse date string internally ;)

Comment: try with date.js or moment.js

Comment: Its also possible to mix and match libraries. `date.js` is good for custom parsing and `XDate` is good for manipulation such as counting difference in days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, there is a Date.parse function but it is implementation dependent and thus unreliable. Your best bet is to manually parse the date or use a date parser library like datejs.

```
<script language="Javascript" src="date.js" type="text/javascript" />
console.log(Date.parseExact ('07Apr2014', 'ddMMMyyyy'))
```

Prints:

```
Date {Mon Apr 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseDate(s) {

    var months = [ "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec" ];

    var monthStarts;
    var yearStarts;

    for (var i=1; i<s.length; i++) {

        var currentCharIsNumb = !isNaN(parseInt(s[i]));
        var previousCharWasNumb = !isNaN(parseInt(s[i -1]));

        if (!currentCharIsNumb && previousCharWasNumb)
            monthStarts = i;
        if (currentCharIsNumb && !previousCharWasNumb)
            yearStarts = i;
    }

    var day = parseInt(s.substring(0, monthStarts));

    var monthStr = s.substring(monthStarts, yearStarts);
    var month = months.indexOf(monthStr.toLowerCase().substring(0, 3));
    var year = parseInt(s.substring(yearStarts));

    return new Date(year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date format appears not to be part of the formats supported by Date.parse method. 
As you already figured out, it appears we need some custom implementation.
Here is a blog that you might find useful/adopt:
http://lpicquet.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/simpledateformat-in-javascript/